# SQL Server - Ole Automation Procedures Inside Queue Activation Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, service-broker, ole-automation

I want to call a Webservice when a row inserted into a table.
So I enable `Ole Automation Procedures`, call Webservice like below and everything goes fine.

```
--enabling 'Ole Automation Procedures'
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  

--calling Webservice
create PROCEDURE callwebservice
@url varchar(128)=null  
AS
    Declare @Object as Int;
    Declare @ResponseText as varchar(8000);
    Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0', @Object OUT;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @url ,'false'

    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
    Exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'ResponseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
    Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
return
```

But, Since Webservice call is extremely lengthy, I need to do it with Service Broker. so I create a new stored-procedure and pass it as an activation parameter of my `Queue` like this:

```
--declare procedure
create procedure handleNewMessageInQueue
as
begin
DECLARE @TargetDlgHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @ReplyMessage xml
DECLARE @ReplyMessageName 
BEGIN TRAN;
receive top(1) 
@TargetDlgHandle =Conversation_handle
,@ReplyMessage = Message_Body
,@ReplyMessageName = Message_Type_Name
from newUserQueue;
if @ReplyMessageName = '//goodType'
begin
    exec callwebservice 'http://path/to/my/webservice'
end
commit tran;
end

--declare queue
create queue myQueue
    with ACTIVATION (
    PROCEDURE_NAME = handleNewMessageInQueue,
    MAX_QUEUE_READERS =100,
    EXECUTE AS owner
);
```

But this time, no request sent. I checked and I realize that the `sp_OACreate` method does not create the Object since the value of `@Object` is `null` after execution of it. Also when I call `sp_OAGetErrorInfo` to get error info, everything is `null`

I'm using SQL Server 2016

I appreciate if you can find the problem here.

**EDIT**

I found that if I enable `TRUSTWORTHY` on that database everything goes fine. but enabling it  [can open security hole](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2183687/guidelines-for-using-the-trustworthy-database-setting-in-sql-server).

is there any better way to do that?

Comment: You have to check the error status after each sp_oaxxx call.  And you should really use SQL CLR or an external program to do this.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft as you said, I checked the error after any call to sp_oaxxx but I got no error from any of the calls. BTY whats wrong with this solution, to the best of my knowledge the service call is running asynchronous and it will not block the main transaction.

Comment: There is no call to sp_OAGetErrorInfo in the procedure you posted.  And what's wrong with this solution is that these are old, little-used, and difficult.  Basically all the reasons you don't already have a working solution.